# MS Access loop items on a report

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2016. I want iterate through the controls on a report.

```
Dim objrpt As AccessObject
Dim ctl As Control
    Set objrpt = CurrentProject.AllReports("Quote")
    Debug.Print objrpt.Name

For Each ctl In objrpt.Controls
    Debug.Print ctl.Name
Next
```

However, an error pops up on the 5th line "For Each ctl In objrpt.Controls"

> Run-time error "438"
>   object does not support this property or method.

Appreciated if anyone could throw some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different report collections in Access. The `AccessObject` report collection, under `CurrentProject.Reports`, is mainly used for exporting.

You're looking for the `Application.Reports` collection, which contains the currently open reports:

```vb
Dim objrpt As Report
Dim ctl As Control
    Set objrpt = Application.Reports("Quote")
    Debug.Print objrpt.Name

For Each ctl In objrpt.Controls
    Debug.Print ctl.Name
Next
```

Note that, for this to work, the report has to be opened.